# Why do I get JRRuntimeException: couldn't load the following font, Helvetica?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

i'm using iReport 5.6 and JDK 6. when i call my report through my Java application this exception appears.
i'm using a special font type and i have added to the iReport Libraries.

The Exception is:

```
**JRRuntimeException: couldn't load the following font:
pdfFontName: Helvetica
pdfEncoding: Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded: false**
```

I **don't use** this type of font, the font is use is special and I gave it a name "Arial" and i have imported it to the fonts library of the iReport.
should I add this ttf file to java, and where? and why there exception about font I don't use.

Comment: The true solution is not in the duplicate, since Helvetica is **not** a font you like to use, but in defining a default style see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36518832/5292302) below

Comment: @AlexK this is not the same exception is get.

Answer (score 1):

If you using `Maven` try to add fonts dependency to your `pom.xml` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, you need to add font what you need to your classpath.

Comment: Jasper report font jar does **not** contain Helvetica

Answer (score 1):

That is the **default font** that itext library use when you export to pdf.

To avoid this problem you need to define in your jrxml the default font to be used by setting **default style**

```
<style name="default" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>
```

Where `fontName` corresponds to a font that is included in your font-extension.